# Is my data fit "extreme value distribution" or "normal distribution"?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, extreme-value

I have a large data.frame in R.  I would like to double if its distribution fit normal distribution or extreme value distribution better

Here is my simplified data.frame.

```
x <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,1,5,4,5,5,7,3,2,2,1,1,1,4,9,10))
```

Could you mind to let me know how to do so?  Can I did this analysis with R?

Answer (score 3):

Before considering formal tests, you should try plotting your data. For example,

```
R> #Plot shown below
R> hist(x$A)
#Backs up the plot
R> shapiro.test(x$A)

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

 data:  x$A 
 W = 0.873, p-value = 0.02452
```

It's clear from the histogram, that the data doesn't seem to be Normal. I find that it's helpful to get an idea of what's happening before moving onto formal tests.

[image]

Does your data fit an extreme valued distribution? That's a bit more tricky. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

A good test for normality is the [Shapiro-Wilk test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) which is implemented in R as `shapiro.test(x)`. For general distribution testing there is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) which is also already implemented in R as `ks.test`. In addition there is a short introduction in the R manuals about [examining data distributions](http://cran.us.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Examining-the-distribution-of-a-set-of-data)